# When I try to run the 'MountainCar-v0' gym from Open AI, all I get is a black screen

Tags: python, macos, artificial-intelligence

I am running this on Mac OSX Mojave with Python 3.7

This is the code I am running, it shold run fine because I am following a tutorial by Sentdex. i have also tried adding a time.sleep(0.1) in the loop but that doesn't work either. I'm at a loss here and I just want to be able to run this agent and do some work on it.

**Please help!!**

```
import gym
import time

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
env.reset()

done = False

while not done:
    action = 2
    new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
    env.render()
    time.sleep(0.1)

env.close()
```

Comment: Where you run that code, in jupyter notebook or pycharm ide?

Comment: I write the code in atom and then just run it from the mac terminal.

Comment: I don't have a mac but the code is fine, I tried on my Linux terminal and PyCharm it works well, so maybe you shouldn't tangle with it and try to use an IDE like PyCharm which is the best I think.

Comment: I tried with PyCharm too and it doesn't work, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Oh no, maybe the bug of apple's new system... sorry to hear that. If you're in a hurry, you can try it online, google colab should be a good choice, good luck.